# Activesheet with userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform which is supposed to update different sheets according to combobox "(Select layer to update)" at a time, see attached image, as soon as I press on SAVA DATA button it return error. "Run time error 380" here are my codes. The listbox is supposed to update according the sheet selected under combobox "(Select layer to update)"

[image]

```
.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 28
.ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "30,50,40,40,35,43,43,28,25,25,25,25,37,50,45,55,70,60,47,35,35,40,40,40,40,50,160,40"


If iRow > 1 Then
   .ListBox1.RowSource = "ActiveSheet!A9:AB" & iRow
Else
   .ListBox1.RowSource = "ActiveSheet!A9:AB9"
   
End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RowSource` property requires to assign a string reference prefixed by
the actual **literal** *worksheetname* plus an exclamation mark (e.g. `Sheet1!A9:AB9`),
not by characters starting with "ActiveSheet" as presumably there won't be a sheet named
"ActiveSheet".

If you want to use VBA's `ActiveSheet` property as first part
you could use the following way getting the sheet's **address**  passing the *additional*
`External:=True` argument (attention to `:=`) which returns the fully qualified sheet name as string:

```
    .RowSource = ActiveSheet.Range("A9:AB" & iRow).Address (External:=True)
```

Another way would be to simply join the string parts via the ampersand connector `&`,
e.g.

- `ActiveSheet.Name & "!A9:AB" & iRow` (using the name of ANY active sheet) or
- `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name & "!A9:AB" & iRow` (using the tabular sheet name) or
- `Sheet1.Name & "!A9:AB" & iRow` (using the CodeName)

Comment: @ T.M Thank you for response. i changed the first row which is ```vba    .ListBox1.RowSource = ActiveSheet.Name & "!A9:AB" & iRow. 
 then I am still getting an erro on ```vba    .ListBox1.RowSource = "ActiveSheet!A9:AB9"
or should i also include name on the last row?

Comment: @EikkydaShidiwe Of course you have to change both assignments, "ActiveSheet!A9:AB9" can't be interpreted correctly as "ActiveSheet" is no actual sheetname, so start here, too with the VBA code: `.RowSource = ActiveSheet.Name & "!A9:AB9"`

Comment: thank you its seems like there's one sheet which is returning an error. " Run time error 380. But other sheet are okay. Sheet named SSG(USSG) as under combobox "select layer to update"

Comment: @EikkydaShidiwe How do you calculate `iRow` and what's the resulting value for the mentioned sheet?

Comment: ``` vba iRow = [Counta(ActiveSheet!A:A)].    if i change it to.  ```vba iRow = [Counta(ActiveSheet.name"!A:A")] 'to identifying the last row.  then it gives an error.

Comment: Once again the same misunderstanding: there is no sheet named "ActiveSheet". If you stick to *VBA's* `ActiveSheet` and are using *Excel's* `CountA`  in a **VBA evaluation** you would have to join the formula parts as string within `Evaluate` instead of brackets `[]`: `iRow = Evaluate("=Counta(" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!A:A)")` and be aware that `CountA` omits empty cells(!). Slightly better instead: `iRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`. - *Generally I'd avoid `ActiveSheet` references wherever possible.* @EikkydaShidiwe

Comment: thank you, it works. but i still have one sheet which is not picking up the correct row source, its goes to a wrong sheet.

Comment: You are welcome. - Of course `ActiveSheet`  can be any sheet currently active and not the one you have in mind, especially if you *selected* another one somewhere else in your code (c.f. [how to avoid using `Select` in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/23913882?r=SearchResults&s=3|25.6194#23913882))

Comment: i will be back with more question.